# SQL Server - Bulk Insert - FIELDQUOTE does not recognize double quote

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to BULK INSERT a CSV table. Some of the fields have values like this: "Smith, John"
Because the comma is in the 'field' - it's 'delimiting' and placing 'John' in the next column.

Here's a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_CSV](
    [a] [int] NULL,
    [b] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [c] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [d] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here's a sample CSV file:

```
2,"2","Mary Smith ","Ms."
1,"1","Smith, John","Mr."
```

Here's the command I'm using

```
BULK INSERT Test_CSV FROM  'C:\MyCSV.csv' with (  FIELDQUOTE='"', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )
```

Here's the data, which is WRONG, I get '[image: BAD PARSING]

Notice column d containing ' **John","Mr."**

What is the correct command?  thx in advance

Comment: That image looks like SSMS 2008, `FIELDQUOTE` was added in SQL Server 2017. If you are using SSMS 2008, then you can't be using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU9) (KB4341265) - 14.0.3030.27 (X64) 
 Jun 29 2018 18:02:47 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: What compatibility level is the database in?

Comment: You need to add FORMAT='CSV' to your WITH statement, then it will work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
BULK INSERT Test_CSV
FROM  'C:\MyCSV.csv' 
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!! I can't believe this works now!!!!! So many years of doing crazy replace logic on .CSV files!!!! Better late than never!

Comment: Imagine not implementing the CSV spec for importing CSV files until 2017. This is crazy. This answer is a godsend.